# database design with two diferrent table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am beginner in DBMS. I am working on a project on Result Analysis for practice on java and database using MySQL Server 5.5. My question is I have an database with two tables cred(uid,pass) [Click here for cred image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qj0mf0qab9rxaj6/cred.png?dl=0) and ht_no(year,subcod,sub,regsup,inter,exter,tot,credit) [Click here for ht_no image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auvk7sd7586hmnx/Ht_no.png?dl=0), where HT_no is the Hall Ticket No. of student.

The two tables doesn't any relation and association. Whether it is possible to create database design for the above table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to associate the two tables? Your objective isn't clear.

Comment: *"...HT_no is the Hall Ticket No. of student."* No, it's not. That's the name of a table. You don't seem to be storing a hall ticket number (whatever that is) at all. If the hall ticket number is supposed to be associated with a particular student (?), you probably need to store the student's identifier in the "ht_no" table.

Comment: yes. i want 2 associate the both tables. @kittykittybangbang

Comment: Ht_no is the Hall ticket no.of the student which is unique. The table name is stored with the Ht_no of the student. Let me say an example HT_no:11qn1a0531. The table name will be saved with that Ht_no., the data in the table will be the results of that particular ht_no. In the same way I have different table with different HT_no. @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Comment: *" The table name is stored with the Ht_no..."* Storing table names as data is a *really* bad idea. No good will come of this.

Answer (score 0):

### **Associating Tables in a Database**

**One-to-One Relationships**

In a one-to-one relationship, each row in Table A is associated to *one and only one* row in Table B. In this case, the `PRIMARY KEY` for each table should 1) uniquely identify the row's subject, and 2) implicitly associate the two tables. For example:

```
Table A
customer_id | name | address | phone

Table B
customer_id | loyalty_card_number | balance
```

However, if you find that your tables share a one-to-one relationship, you're probably doing it wrong: In most cases, it would be beneficial to simply combine these two tables into one, thus reducing performance overheads to the database engine.

**One-to-Many Relationships**

In a one-to-many relationship, each row in Table A can be associated to many rows in Table B. Each row in Table B, however, should associate with one and only one row in Table A. In this case, the `PRIMARY KEY` for Table A should be included as an additional column in Table B to associate the two tables. For example:

```
Table A 
customer_id | name | address | phone

Table B
credit_card_number | card_provider | customer_id
```

This allows each customer to be associated to more than one credit card, but each credit card will belong to one and only one customer.

**Many-to-Many Relationships**

In a many-to-many relationship, each row in Table A can be associated to 0, 1, or more rows in Table B, *and vice versa*. That is to say, each row in Table B may also be related to 0, 1, or more rows in Table A. For a many-to-many relationship, a third table, called a *mapping table*, is required to associate the two tables. For example:

```
Table A
customer_id | name | address | phone

Table B
product_id | name | price

Table C
customer_id | product_id
```

Here, each customer may have 0, 1, or many products (s)he may have purchased; likewise, each product may have been purchased by 0, 1, or many customers. The most efficient way to deal with this is to use Table C to map each relationship, using the `PRIMARY KEY` for each customer and each product to associate the two.